# 2 absolute Boxes below each other..?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Sry my english is bad.. I got 2 Boxes, one at the bottom left, the other at the bottom right, both with position:absolute and bottom: 0px;. When I make the window smaller, they overlap ... but they should go below each other (got no code for that yet). Tried with max-width but I guess the "poition:absolute;" destroys it.

```
    <body>
    <div id="nav">
        <p><a href="">MUSIC</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="">RADIO & LIVE CHAT</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="">SHOP</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="">COMMUNITY</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="">SUBMIT</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="">CONTACT</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="iconrow">
        <a href="">
            <img src="../bilder/youtube.png" class="iconrow"/>
        </a>
        <a href="">
            <img src="../bilder/soundcloud.png" class="iconrow"/>
        </a>
        <a href="">
            <img src="../bilder/spotify.png" class="iconrow"/>
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
#nav {
font-family:Typograph;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
right: 0px;
padding: 0px 40px 10px 0px;
font-size: 18px;}
#iconrow {
position:absolute;
bottom: 0px;}
.iconrow {
width:50px;
float:left;
padding: 0px 0px 25px 20px;}
```

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Comment: `absolute` elements have no knowledge of each other's presence when it comes to document flow. That's kind of the point of them. You might want to use media queries to detect when the view is too small to fit both.

Answer (score 1):

Position absolute will exactly prevent you from achieving that. 
What you need is two boxes with width of 50%, floating (e.g. to the left) and then a media query which adjusts the width of the box to 100% under a particular screen size.

Comment: Or just simply setting `position: relative` in media query

Answer (score 0):

Use a media Query, define the height of `#icon-row` and assign that height value as a `bottom` value to `#nav`. Plus a few other details - see my snippet.

```css
  #nav {
  font-family: Typograph;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 0px 40px 10px 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#iconrow {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 70px;
}

.iconrow {
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 0px 25px 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  #nav,
  #iconrow {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #nav {
    bottom: 70px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  }
  .iconrow {
  float: none;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="nav">
    <p><a href="">MUSIC</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="">RADIO & LIVE CHAT</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="">SHOP</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="">COMMUNITY</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="">SUBMIT</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="">CONTACT</a></p>
  </div>
  <div id="iconrow">
    <a href="">
      <img src="../bilder/youtube.png" class="iconrow" />
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <img src="../bilder/soundcloud.png" class="iconrow" />
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <img src="../bilder/spotify.png" class="iconrow" />
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
```